# Specifying Depends correctly in debian/control file

Tags: linux, debian, shared-library, debian-policy

I'm building a runtime-shared-library package `libfoo0.deb` where `0` here is a major package version and adhering to the naming conventions specified in the [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#development-files).

The problem is I want to build another shared library `libbar` depending on the runtime shared library package `libfoo0`. So I'm considering adding a depends stanza, but I'm not sure if it is necessary to specify a version, like

```
Depends: libfoo0 (= 0.0.4)
```

The `0.0.4` here is the version of `libfoo0-dev.deb` (package containing development files/necessary symlinks in `/usr/lib/`) with which the `libbar` was built. The problem I see is that would prohibit users from updating `libfoo0`.

***Question:*** As long as `libfoo0` is binary backward compatible across major library version isn't it required to specify a dependency on the exact version of `libfoo0` a library/binary was built with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your build includes `dh_shlibdeps` or `dpkg-shlibdeps` (if you’re using `dh`, this will be taken care of), you should add

```
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}
```

to `libbar`’s `control` file, and the appropriate dependencies will be added for you.

You shouldn’t hard-code a specific version, unless libraries need to be upgraded in lockstep. The idea is that libraries with the same major version are supposed to be backwards-compatible, so as long as you have a version greater than or equal to the one you need, you should be OK. The tools will also take care of this for you; you might need to manually add a `shlibs` or `symbols` file to `libfoo`; IIRC the build will tell you when you need to deal with that.

Comment: This is not directly to the question, but I'd like to ask about best practices of packaging development files. Currently my `libfoo0` and `libfoo0-dev` are independent and `libfoo0-dev` contains all the files `libfoo0` does and headers needed to compile binaries. So when `libfoo0` is installed attempting to install `libfoo0-dev` fails because of it contains the files of `libfoo0`. Would not it be better to make `libfoo0-dev` depending on `libfoo0` of the same version.

Comment: Yes, your `-dev` package should depend on the library package with the same version. You probably should name it `libfoo-dev`, not `libfoo0-dev`.

Comment: The reason I added major version to the development package name was to support multiple development versions. Does not it make any sense?

Comment: It does make sense in some circumstances but IME it causes more problems than it solves. Obviously if you know you need to be able to install multiple development versions in parallel, go for it; but be aware that it complicates migrations an awful lot.

Comment: And if you provide multiple development packages, those should carry the *API* version in their names. (I think this mostly makes sense if they're co-installable.) On the other hand the library packages carry the SO version (derived from the *ABI* version) in their names. So the numbers in libfooX and libfooY-dev are unrelated.